# android LogCat only outputting last line

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

sometimes when i work on android in eclipse the logcat output just seems to output the last line of messages and discards everything before.

this usually happens after 30mins of work but i cant find a concrete way to repro it.

any hints? thanks!

Comment: You rather use the original logcat through a command line... you can combine it with this colorizer: http://jsharkey.org/blog/2009/04/22/modifying-the-android-logcat-stream-for-full-color-debugging/ which will make it look really nice and useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes your device becomes unselected in DDMS. Next time you have this problem, open the DDMS perspective in Eclipse and re-click your device in the devices window.

That usually does the trick for me.

Comment: Showing only the last line indicates that the the device is selected.

Comment: Not always in my experience.  Sometimes it is selected but in a stuck state (hence showing 1 line).  Selecting something else, then selecting the device again fixes it for me.

Comment: This answer is not correct to the exact question asked. The question relates to the problem of the buffer becoming full at which point logcat only displays the last 1 or 2 lines in the log. I get around this by simply clicking the "Clear Log" icon at the right of the Eclipse logcat pane whenever i see the single line. What Josh refers to is ANOTHER issue with logcat where Yes, eclipse sometimes loses the device OR doesn't auto select it to begin with. Just my 2 cents

Comment: Oddly enough, this advice fixed another rather weird problem I was having with logcat.

Answer (score 16):

The eclipse DDMS buffer is unnecessarily small. You can click the clear log button and it will start showing the log again. I'm not sure if there's a way to increase the buffer or not. I always look at the logcat in the terminal. Here's a really good python script that adds color to the output.

http://jsharkey.org/blog/2009/04/22/modifying-the-android-logcat-stream-for-full-color-debugging/

Comment: thanks clearing the log sometimes help, but still after a while nothing seems to bet outputted anymore and not even clearing seems to help.

Comment: this is the correct answer. Josh's answer refers another issue in Eclipse where the active device is sometimes unselected or not auto selected to begin with...